# Cannot find name 'attributes'. Amplify Auth

Tags: angular, typescript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I've added an authorization to my angular app using `amplify add auth`. 
After that I've added

```
"requiredAttributes": [
    "email",
    "custom:firstName",
    "custom:lastName"
],
```

to the amplify/backend/auth/XXX/parameters.json

and

```
  Schema:

    -
      Name: email
      Required: true
      Mutable: true

    -
      AttributeDataType: "String"
      Mutable: true
      Name: firstName
      StringAttributeConstraints:
        MaxLength: 256
        MinLength: 1

    -
      AttributeDataType: "String"
      Mutable: true
      Name: lastName
      StringAttributeConstraints:
        MaxLength: 256
        MinLength: 1
```

to the amplify/backend/auth/XXX/XXX-cloudformation-template.yml

After that `amplify push`.

I can see these custom filds in Console:
[image]

but when I try to send custom fields like this:

```
  import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

  ...

  signUp(email, password, firstName, lastName): Observable<any> {
    return fromPromise(Auth.signUp(
      email,
      password,
      attributes: {
        "custom:firstName": firstName,
        "custom:lastName": lastName
      }
    ));
  }
```

TypeScript compiler thrown this error:

> Cannot find name 'attributes'.ts

It should be:

`signUp(params: string | SignUpParams, ...restOfAttrs: string[]): Promise<ISignUpResult>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my workaround:

```
  signUp(username, password, firstName, lastName): Observable<any> {
    const signUpParams: any = {
      username,
      password,
      attributes: {
        'custom:firstName': firstName,
        'custom:lastName': lastName
      }
    };
    return fromPromise(Auth.signUp(
      signUpParams
    ));
  }
```